# $http POST angular-Submit constant public key at the time of login

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I need to submit public key with constant key value, along with username and password at the time of login.And also to redirect it some other page in ionic app- href="#/tab/abc", if login is successful. Is this a right way:

Controller.js

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state,$http, $rootScope,$window,$location) {
   $scope.formData = {};
   $scope.processForm = function() {
           $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'api/login ',
              data    : $.param($scope.formData),  
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
              })
        .success(function (response) {

                  $scope.data=response;
                  $state.go('tab.abc');
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $window.alert("username or password incorrect");
        });
      };

   })
```

How to submit this public key" X-API-KEY=eroo9rwabcor-ltjabcerabc9r" along with username and password at the time of login. And then redirect it to some other page in ionic app.

html

```
   <form action="" class="ki-login-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"  >
            <div class="form-group username">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model="formData.username" value="" id="identity" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group pin">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="formData.password" value="" id="identity" placeholder="Your Pin">
            </div>
            <a type="submit" class="btns" ng-click="processForm(formData.username,formData.password)">Login</a>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to pass it through headers.

```
$http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : 'api/login ',
    data    : $.param($scope.formData),  
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-API-KEY': 'eroo9rwabcor-ltjabcerabc9r' }  
})
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.data=response;
    $location.path('#/tab/abc');
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    $window.alert("username or password incorrect");
});
```

Comment: Yes it's working but not redirecting page to $location.path('#/tab/abc');

Comment: If possible use $state.go('<state name>'), which is the preferred method. or do an $scope.$apply(); after $location.path().